# Laravel - Check for another URL prefix if exists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

How can I skip a wildcard Route to check for another Route before returning it as 404?

```
Route::get( '{user}', function( $user ){
   // Checking for existing user
   if( $user = User::getUser( $user ) )
       return view( 'templates.user', [ 'user' => $user ] );

   // Should check another prefixes before return 404

   return abort( 404 );
});

Route::get( 'foopage', function(){ return view( 'templates.foo' ); });
```

From the code above, if I access `/foopage` it returns 404 because of no username 'foopage' exist.

But it's supposed to show `view( 'templates.foo' )`

Comment: Put foopage before {user} ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the statement 
`Route::get( 'foopage', function(){ return view( 'templates.foo' ); });`

above the user route statement.

```
Route::get( '{user}', function( $user ){
   ...
 });
```

This is because laravel prioritise the order of routes defined and if the foopage route is defined below the user routes, it will consider foobar to be a user route and try to go down that path.

Comment: Thanks for the quick! I was just thinking of  
_'how if I have multiple wildcard check?'_
but it's nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need a multiple wildcard check, I brought this answer

Going with `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag` I just build a new alias that runs `ParameterBag::add()` also `ParameterBag::get()`

Next in the routes/web.php

```
// Create the wildcard route
Route::get( '{user}', function( $user ){
    $template = ParameterBag::get( 'template' );
    $userdata = ParameterBag::get( 'userdata' );

    return view( $template, [ 'userdata' => $userdata  ] );
})->middleware( 'userroute' );
```

Create a custom `$routeMiddleware` in App\Http\Kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    ....
    'userroute' => \App\Http\Middleware\WildcardRoutes::class,
];
```

And the handler in App\Http\Middleware\WildcardRoutes.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use ParameterBag; // I have this alias in app.php
use User; // alias about Users
use Group; // alias about Groups

class WildcardRoutes{
    public function __construct(){ /* do anything */ }

    /* Handle an incoming request. */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        // Check if user exists
        if( $user = User::getUser( $request->user ) ){
            // When exist store the information
            ParameterBag::add( [ 'userdata' => $user, 'template' => 'templates.user' ] );

            return $next($request); // means everything going well
        }

        // Checking in the group
        if( $group = Group::getGroup( $request->user ) ){
            // When exist store the information
            ParameterBag::add( [ 'userdata' => $group, 'template' => 'templates.group' ] );

            return $next($request);
        }

        // When nothing found
        return abort(404);
    }
}
```